# Same ItemsSource in multiple ComboBox elements, SelectedIndex synced for all ComboBox elements, want separate

Tags: wpf, combobox, itemssource, selectedindex

I have multiple ComboBox elements. Each ComboBox's ItemsSource is bound to the same property.  That property is a ListCollectionView whose underlying list is an ObservableCollection.  Each ComboBox's SelectedIndex is bound to a different property.  My problem is that when the user changes one ComboBox all the others are changed to the same item.

How can I make the SelectedIndex properties independent?  Do I need to use something other than ListCollectionView or ObservableCollection?  Would binding to something other than SelectedIndex help?

Answer (score 0):

After some poking around I found that the ComboBox property IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem fixed my problem.  When set to false my ComboBoxes became independent.